# Live Data search problem, how to notify user to be more specific in search

Tags: json, ajax

I'm trying to utilize a Live search demo I found on the web utilizing php, ajax and json and would like to make some slight modification to the code to ask the user to be "more specific" in the query so as not to query the entire database.

I'd like to limit the return query to no more than 50 records and if the query has more than that to give notice to the user.

Here is the source I'm trying to modify (https://howtodecode.com/php/how-to-create-php-live-search-with-ajax-for-website/).

In my code below I've tried to modify the json but I have no knowledge of its implementation so I'm struggling with where the error is in my code.

I'm seeing the following in the RESPONSE "{"F_NAME":"...please narrow your seach, too many records to display.","L_NAME":""}". This appears to be correct but I can't get it to parse correctly.

I'm getting "No Data Found".

```
    <?php
require_once('../TestSearch/Connections/Shop.php');

//fetch.php

$query = '';

if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = str_replace(",", "|", $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
 SELECT F_NAME, L_NAME, JOB_NO, CUST_NO, DESCRIPTIN, JOB_TYPE FROM line_job 
 WHERE F_NAME REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR L_NAME REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR JOB_NO REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR CUST_NO REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR DESCRIPTIN REGEXP '".$search."'
  OR JOB_TYPE REGEXP '".$search."'
 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "
 SELECT F_NAME, L_NAME, JOB_NO, CUST_NO, DESCRIPTIN, JOB_TYPE FROM line_job WHERE line_job = 47779
 ";
}

$result = $mysqli -> query($query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 50)
{
    $data = ['F_NAME' => '...please narrow your seach, too many records to display.','L_NAME' => ''];
    echo json_encode($data);
}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   
    {
     $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

and here is the script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 load_data();

 function load_data(query)
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#total_records').text(data.length);
    var html = '';
    if(data.length > 0)
    {
     for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
     {
      html += '<tr>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].F_NAME+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].L_NAME+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].JOB_NO+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].CUST_NO+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].DESCRIPTIN+'</td>';
      html += '<td>'+data[count].JOB_TYPE+'</td></tr>';
     }
    }
    else
    {
     html = '<tr><td colspan="5">No Data Found</td></tr>';
    }
    $('tbody').html(html);
   }
  })
 }

 $('#search').click(function(){
  var query = $('#tags').val();
  load_data(query);
 });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my problem by slightly re-coding the php and limiting the query result to 50.

```
<?php
require_once('../TestSearch/Connections/Shop.php');

//fetch.php

$query = '';

if(isset($_POST["query"]) and !empty($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = str_replace(",", "|", $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
 SELECT F_NAME, L_NAME, JOB_NO, CUST_NO, DESCRIPTIN, JOB_TYPE FROM line_job 
 WHERE F_NAME REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR L_NAME REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR JOB_NO REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR CUST_NO REGEXP '".$search."' 
 OR DESCRIPTIN REGEXP '".$search."'
  OR JOB_TYPE REGEXP '".$search."'
 LIMIT 50
 ";
}
else
{
// if the form is submitted with no search criteria ""
$data = "";
echo json_encode($data);    
exit;
}


$result = $mysqli -> query($query);
//determine if the query returned a result or are there no records that match
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result); 

if($rowcount > 0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))   
{
 $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data);

}
else
{
$data = "";
echo json_encode($data);
}


?>
```